# Hyper error: invalid certificate: UnknownIssuer

Tags: rust, hyper, rust-warp

(I am adding this question after finding the solution as there was no matches for my error when I needed it.)

After packaging a rust app as a docker container, I get the following error: `Hyper error: invalid certificate: UnknownIssuer`.

I have used the example from the official rust docker image (cf. https://hub.docker.com/_/rust/):

```
FROM rust:1.40 as builder
WORKDIR /usr/src/myapp
COPY . .
RUN cargo install --path .

FROM debian:buster-slim
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install
COPY --from=builder /usr/local/cargo/bin/myapp /usr/local/bin/myapp
CMD ["myapp"]
```

Answer (score 4):

The issue was that the debian docker image does not include the `ca-certificate` package. The issue was solved using:

```
FROM rust:1.40 as builder
WORKDIR /usr/src/myapp
COPY . .
RUN cargo install --path .

FROM debian:buster-slim
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends ca-certificates
COPY --from=builder /usr/local/cargo/bin/myapp /usr/local/bin/myapp
CMD ["myapp"]
```